# How can assign an EntityID to an entity of a shard in Akka.NET?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, sharding, akka.net

I don't understand how ID's are assign when you create a new actor in a ShardRegion, I was looking through this example

https://github.com/akkadotnet/akka.net/tree/dev/src/examples/Cluster/ClusterSharding/ClusterSharding.Node

If someone has a more clearer example that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

All messages targeting sharded actors (entities) must come through the shard region responsible for the givent type of the entity. A shard region can be initialized like this:

```
var sharding = ClusterSharding.Get(system);
var shardRegion = sharding.Start(
    typeName: nameof(MyActor), 
    entityProps: Props.Create<MyActor>(), // the Props used to create entities
    settings: ClusterShardingSettings.Create(system),
    messageExtractor: messageExtractor
);
```

In order to correctly route messages to entities, shard region must be able to extract the shard-id and entity-id of that entity and a shard, it belongs to. This is a job of a `messageExtractor` object (it must implement `IMessageExtractor` interface).

A common pattern here is to create a dedicated envelope used to route the actual messages to entities. Below you can see an example - shard id is not provided explicitly, instead it's calculated from the hash of the entity id modulo maximum number of shards (this value, once picked, must never change).

```
public sealed class ShardEnvelope
{
    public readonly string EntityId;
    public readonly object Payload;

    public ShardEnvelope(string entityId, object payload)
    {
        EntityId = entityId;
        Payload = payload;
    }
}

public sealed class MessageExtractor : HashCodeMessageExtractor
{
    public MessageExtractor(int maxNumberOfShards) : base(maxNumberOfShards) { }
    public override string EntityId(object message) => 
        (message as ShardEnvelope)?.EntityId;
    public override object EntityMessage(object message) => 
        (message as ShardEnvelope)?.Payload;
}
```

Now, while entities lifecycle is fully managed by cluster sharding and their actual localization within a cluster may change over time (due to rebalancing), their relative path inside the given cluster node always stays the same, and it conforms to the following pattern:

```
/user/sharding/<typeName>/<shard-id>/<entity-id>
```

It means that, **if you want to extract entity-id and shard-id of your current actor, you can do that directly from actor's path**:

```
var entityId = Self.Path.Name;
var shardId = Self.Path.Parent.Name;
```